# Hector/Cassandra: How do I add a Column to an existing SuperColumn?

Tags: cassandra, hector

I can create a new SuperColumn that has Columns - no problem.  I can create a new Column - no problem.  But how do I add a new Column to an existing SuperColumn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But how do I add a new Column to an existing SuperColumn?

You should really look into the class `SuperCfTemplate` and class `SuperCfUpdater` in hector. Once they are initialize, do what is needed (example in your question, add a new cf within this scf), then update the changes using the template. Below are a snippet.

```
SuperCfTemplate<String, String, String> template = new ThriftSuperCfTemplate<String, String, String>(keyspace, "Super1", stringSerializer, stringSerializer, stringSerializer);
SuperCfUpdater<String, String, String> updater = template.createUpdater("key", "newcf");
updater.setString("subname", "1");
template.update(updater);
```

Comment: But, if I just want to add the column definition without a key?

Comment: @Joeya without a key, how should that row be identified or where should the row store? Please read this [link](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/DataModel#Rows) for more information.